# Handle dialog immediately opened in new tab

Tags: playwright

I'm writing a Playwright test for the case in which a link opens an application via a new tab. The user clicks a link, and a new tab is opened with a custom application url.

The browser normally asks "Do you want to open this link," and the user must click accept or cancel.

In Playwright, the new page is blocked until *after* the dialog is confirmed. If I don't have access to the page, is it somehow possible to listen for the dialog event?

```
const context = page.context();

async function newPageOpened(): Promise<void> {
  const newPage = await context.waitForEvent('page')
  // I won't have access to newPage unless I manually click the Accept button 

  newPage.on('dialog', (dialog) => {
    void dialog.accept();
  });
}

async function action(): Promise<void> {
  // Click the link
}

await Promise.all([newPageOpened, action()])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is a Chrome (only) implementation. Playwright doesn't know how to handle them. So, you won't be able to dismiss it using the `dialog` event.
You can follow this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11014).